# unable to navigate using routerlink

Tags: typescript, angular6

I am trying to navigate to detail of customer but I am getting

> Error: "[object object]"

Can someone help me to figure this out? I am new to angular so it would mean a lot to me. Thanks in advance!

customer-list.html

```
<p *ngFor="let c of customers">
  <a [routerLink]="['detail']" [queryParams]="{id: c.id}">{{c.name}}</a>
</p>
```

customer-detail.ts

```
  customer: Customer;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private cs: CustomerService) {
    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.customer = this.cs.getCustomerById(params['id']);
    });
  }
```

customer.service.ts

```
get customers() {
  return this._customers;
}

getCustomerById(id: number) {
  for (let i = 0; i > this._customers.length; i++) {
    const customer = this._customers[i];

    if (customer.id == id) {
      return customer;
    }
  }
 return null;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK neither `routerLink` nor its value need to be in square brackets.
Have you tried `<a routerLink="detail" ...` already?

Comment: i tried with that as well but no luck

Comment: @LamaN, please, did you solve this issue ?